# Pytorch reports CUDA out of memory on print statement

Tags: python, pytorch

I found a funny issue - if you allocate a CUDA tensor which takes up almost all of the memory on your GPU with `dtype=torch.float16`, trying to print the tensor will give an out of memory error. My best guess is that for some reason it is casting up to a larger datatype but I have no clue what is happening internally, or why. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on how the object implements `__str__` or `__repr__`.

Comment: Of course, the print method will call `__str__`. I'm just curious as to what is actually happening there.

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

Comment: I don't think this should be closed - ping me if it is, I'll vote reopen.

Comment: interesting, I think you can get a better answer if you ask the same question in [pytorch issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues) or [their forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/)